# How to insert tab character in Text mode?

Tags: emacs, whitespace

I have tried to parse a file `language_data.txt,` which is edited by Emacs. The different columns are separated by tab characters.

But when I opened the file, I found that each of the tab characters had been replaced by many space characters. For example:

```
en_US   shiphrah        02005   book reader no connection
en_US   shiphrah        02006   user reader no connection
```

How to insert a tab character in Text mode?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`C-q <tab>`

C-q insert the next character as a raw character

Comment: C-q is bound by default to the function ```quoted-insert```, so more specifically, this is ```M-x quoted-insert <tab>```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to answer given: Check value of `indent-tabs-mode`, customize it if needed.
Several hooks use it's value doing translations TAB-Blank.

Answer (score 4):

If you want TAB key to insert a tab character, add this to your ~/.emacs

`(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'self-insert-command);`

More helpful info on emacs + TAB : https://web.archive.org/web/20160312104535/http://vserver1.cscs.lsa.umich.edu/~rlr/Misc/emacs_tabs.htm

Answer (score 1):

Addition to [@Vash2593](https://superuser.com/a/602511/520071) answer.

If you want to insert tab to more than one line. You can use `indent-rigidly` which is bound to `C-x TAB`. Then you can move the indentation interactively with `S-left` or `S-right`.

Or you can supply with emacs universal argument `C-u`. e.g `C-u 4 C-x TAB` to add 4 spaces. `C-u -4 C-x TAB` to remove 4 spaces.

This is very handy when it comes to formatting codes in social forums. Which need 4 spaces indent.